# How to test external APIs?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am having a hard time on how to start testing the integration with an external API ( Vimeo API ) for things like ( deleting a video - uploading a video - etc..).

- Should I hit the real Vimeo's server while testing?

Is it a bad idea to do this like:

```php
use Tests\TestCase;
use Vimeo\Laravel\VimeoManager;

class VimeoApiTest extends TestCase
{
    protected function setUp() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->vimeo = new VimeoManager();
    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_video_can_be_deleted()
    {
        $video = $this->vimeo->upload($fakeVideo);

        // make http request to delete the video
        $result = $this->vimeo->delete($video['id']);

        $this->assertEquals('success', $result['status']);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't test, you mock them

Comment: You can mock them by https://themockapis.in/

Comment: Most of the other answers/comments say that you should mock the response. While this is true, it doesn't hurt to have one true end-to-end test that actually hits the 3rd party server. This is helpful when using a CI/CD pipeline, where the E2E test will notify of downtimes and potentially incorrect response payloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my eyes testing a package should not be your responsibility. Testing your implementation of the package is. Your example tests the package's `VimeoManager` directly. Which is in my opinion not what you should do.

Making a request to your API route that uploads the video is what you should test. During this test you do not want to upload it to the real Vimeo API, but you want to mock it.

Laravel includes a package that can do this, it is called [Mockery](https://github.com/mockery/mockery). You can mock methods of classes to return a value without the initial logic being executed. In this case you would mock the `delete` method of the `VimeoManager`.

Laravel also provides so called [`Facades`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/mocking) which can easily be [mocked](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/mocking#mocking-facades). I can see this package [makes use of such facade](https://github.com/vimeo/laravel/blob/master/src/Facades/Vimeo.php). In this case you can do the following to test implemention of lets say your delete request.

```php
/** @test */
use Vimeo\Laravel\Facades\Vimeo;

public function your_test()
{
    Vimeo::shouldReceive('delete')
        ->once()
        ->with(...) // The parameters is should receive.
        ->andReturn(...); // The value it should return.

    // Make the delete request to your API.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can test however you see fit. I've find it useful to have two types of tests.

A test which interacts with "something" else (service, system, etc...) is known as an integration test. These are nice and give some piece of mind, but are linked to the system that you are interacting with being online, this isn't always the case.

The second type of test can have a couple of different names, but that isn't really the point. The point of this second type of test is that you can "mock" out external/internal dependencies, ensuring that the "thing" your code depends on is online/behaves how you want. Mocking is when you manipulate a "thing" to respond a certain way. Usually, this is done via some framework or language feature. These types of test put a way larger burden on your code, and count more in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm generally against mocking server to which my tests should be connected.
The main disadvantage of mocking servers and use simulators is fact that implementation of API may change (and for example throw exception/new status code or timeouts may be shorter) or there may be not compatibility between APIs between 2 versions of server.

> Should I hit the real Vimeo's server while testing?

If You have possibility then create your local Vimeo's server using docker :)
Your tests will find out if something changes in API in future